# Python code to extract similar key-word with value from a string

Tags: python

String of the command output obtained is as below....

```
Key_word = {"Devices on the system.
           
           Device description: device-1
           Device status: Healthy
           Handle: 0xFF00

           Device description: device-2
           Device status: Healthy
           Handle: 0xC00A
           
           Device description: device-3
           Device status: Healthy
           Handle: 0xDD00"}
```

Required Output :
I want Python code to extract a list like this

```
{'Handle: 0xFF00', Handle: 0xC00A', Handle: 0xDD00}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code lists the required output.....

```
import re
key =  'Handle: 0x[0-9a-fA-F]+'
final_list = []
final_list = re.findall(key, str(input_string))
print(final_list)
```